# mongodb input plugin using logstash elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash

I am getting this error while running the conf file

```
D:\elastic search\logstash-1.5.3\bin>logstash -f mongo.conf
io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated
Warning: No private key present, creating unsigned gem.
The error reported is:
  No connection string specified
```

this is my conf file

```
input {
  mongodb {
    uri => 'mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017/mydb'
    path => '/opt/logstash-mongodb/logstash_sqlite.db'
    collection => 'bike'
    port => 27017
    unpack_mongo_id => true
    batch_size => 5000
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The URI already specified with a port after the host (localhost:27017), there is no need of "port" again. Try using SSL to your URI as mongodb://username:password@host:port/db?ssl=true

Answer (score 0):

Supply `authSource`, `placeholder_db_dir`, `placeholder_db_name` as follows:

```
input {
  mongodb {
    uri => 'mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017/mydb?authSource=admin'
    placeholder_db_dir => 'C:\ELK\logstash-5.3.0\data'
    placeholder_db_name => 'logstash_sqlite.db'
    collection => 'bike'
    unpack_mongo_id => true
    batch_size => 5000
  }
}
```